# Problemas para conectar con el servidor desde IIS

Tags: angularjs, mvc, iis

Estoy intentanto conectar mi aplicacion web publica en IIS con Sql server pero me lanza el siguiente Error:

Login failed for user 'ENT\BERASA3-D1$'.

Comment: No me funciona..

Comment: ¿Lograste hacerlo funcionar?

Comment: Si logre hacerlo funcionar

Comment: Agrega lo que hiciste para que le sea de utilidad a más desarrolladores que tengan el mismo escenario o algo similar. Y en 24 horas marcas la respuesta como aceptada :D